# Show that $(k!)!$ is divisible by $(k!)^{(k-1)!}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, factorial

Question : Show that $(k!)!$ is divisible by $(k!)^{(k-1)!}$.

Answer : Suppose we've $k!$ objects, where k objects of 1st kind, k objects of 2nd kind,...k objects of $(k-1)!$ kind **(why?)**. And from the well known formula we get :

$$ \frac{(k!)!}{k!k!...k!((k-1) times)**(why?)**} = \frac{(k!)!}{(k!)^{(k-1)!}}$$

My question is from where we do we get the idea of having $(k-1)$ in the calculation. I'm confused. Please help me.

Comment: The $k-1$ just comes from the fact that $k! = k\cdot (k-1)!$.  Literally, it is how many copies of $k$ you need to add up to $k!$.  The well known formula is called a multinomial coefficient, which you can Google.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1710120/589 for a different take

Comment: The solution should start by this question: "How many ways can we arrange the list [1,1,1,...,1,2,2,2,...,2,...,(k-1)!,(k-1)!,...] ?"
The answer is the asked quantity since there are exactly k-1!•k = k! objects which can be arranged in (k!)! ways but we over counted so we divide by k!, (k-1)! times since there are (k-1)! "groups" that can be arranged in k! ways

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lfloor r\rfloor$ denote the *floor* of $r$ 
(i.e. the largest integer $\leq r)$.

**Lemma 1** 
For $a \in \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}, ~b\in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~
b\lfloor a\rfloor \leq \lfloor ab\rfloor.$

Proof: 
Let $a = P + r,~~$ where $P \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}, ~~0 \leq r < 1.$ 
Thus, $P = \lfloor a\rfloor$. 
Further, $(ba) - ( bP) = (br).$ 
Let $c = \lfloor (br) \rfloor \implies 0 \leq c.$

Then, $\lfloor (ba) \rfloor = (bP) + c \implies 
\lfloor (ba) \rfloor \geq (bP) = b\lfloor a\rfloor.$

---

Given two positive integers, $a,b$, you can show that $\frac{a}{b}$ is an integer by showing that for any prime $p$, if $p^r$ is in the prime factorization of $b$, then $p^s$ is in the prime factorization of $a$, where $s \geq r.$

Use [Legendre formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula):

$$v_p(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor.$$

In order to show that $(k!)^{(k-1)!}$ divides $[(k!)!]$, it is sufficient to show that for any prime $p$, if $d$ is the largest non-negative integer such that $p^d$ divides $(k!)$, then $p^{d(k-1)!}$ divides $[(k!)!].$

So, by assumption:

$$
\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^1}\right\rfloor ~+~ 
\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^2}\right\rfloor ~+~ 
\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^3}\right\rfloor ~+~ 
\cdots = d.\tag1$$

It is sufficient to prove that :

$$
\left\lfloor \frac{k!}{p^1}\right\rfloor ~+~ 
\left\lfloor \frac{k!}{p^2}\right\rfloor ~+~ 
\left\lfloor \frac{k!}{p^3}\right\rfloor ~+~ 
\cdots \geq d(k-1)!.\tag1$$

However, this result is immediate, by invoking Lemma 1, term by term.

That is:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^1}\right\rfloor \times (k-1)! \leq 
\left\lfloor \frac{k!}{p^1}\right\rfloor.$$

$$\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^2}\right\rfloor \times (k-1)! \leq 
\left\lfloor \frac{k!}{p^2}\right\rfloor.$$

$$\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^3}\right\rfloor \times (k-1)! \leq 
\left\lfloor \frac{k!}{p^3}\right\rfloor.$$

$$\cdots$$